# How to adjust the width of CListCtrl columns to fit the longest string in each column?

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I am trying:

```
void MyListCtrl::UpdateWidthOfColumns( void )
{

  int NofColumns = GetItemCount();
  for (int i = 0; i < NofColumns - 1 ; ++i)
  {
      SetColumnWidth( i, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER );
  }
}
```

**result:** width of each column is adjusted to it`s header string size, not to the largest string.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing this:

```
SetColumnWidth( i, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER );
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761163%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER: Automatically sizes the column to fit the header text.

You need to go through each column, find the longest string:

```
CSize   sz;

for (/*for each column, go through each row*/)
{
   sz = pDC->GetTextExtent(str); // get string size for each row
   if (sz.cx > dx)
      dx = sz.cx;
}
```

Then

// Set the column width to the largest string.

```
SetColumnWidth(dx);
```

Comment: @telkity It seems that in later versions of Windows, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER checks both the header and the longest string.  Can you confirm this?

Comment: @Dan, that seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible with Windows hot key Ctrl Shift Plus

```
m_listLicences.SendMessage(WM_KEYDOWN, VK_CONTROL, 1);
m_listLicences.SendMessage(WM_KEYDOWN, VK_SHIFT, 1);
m_listLicences.SendMessage(WM_KEYDOWN, VK_ADD, 1);
m_listLicences.SendMessage(WM_KEYUP, VK_ADD, 1);
m_listLicences.SendMessage(WM_KEYUP, VK_SHIFT, 1);
m_listLicences.SendMessage(WM_KEYUP, VK_CONTROL, 1);
```